# How to divide a numerical value equally over multiple cells in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have done a fair bit of Googling but unfortunately haven't found what I am looking for.  In an old workplace, we had a keyboard shortcut to perform a specific task and I can't seem to recreate it.

I want to highlight multiple cells (in the same column) and be able to type a numerical value that is then divided equally over all highlighted cells.  The range will be different every time.

Any advice appreciated.  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: you will need to write some vba to do this, there is not a formula that will do this based on the selection of cells.

Comment: OK cool, I think I know how to assign a vba macro to a keyboard shortcut.  It's just the vba code that is not my strong suit.  I imagine the code would go something like identify the range selected, identify the cell with the numeric value (first cell of range, or maybe any cell within range?) then divide the numerical value by the number of cells in range and assign the value into all cells in range?

Comment: Sounds like a good start.  Try coding it on your own(the macro recorder could help).  When you hit a wall, come back with the code you tried and ask a specific question about the specific problem you are having, ie. the error or wrong output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually that can be done with one line of code:

```
Selection.Value = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Number to distribute", Type:=1) / Selection.Cells.Count
```

Devide the number you input in `InputBox` by the amount of selected cells `Selection.Cells.Count` and write that into the selected cells `Selection.Value`.